# mesh is twisting on bezier circle

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

after managing to get the mesh to follow the bezier circle theres a problem where it twists and screws up in one corner but the other corner seems fine. if it matters the origin point is at the top of the curve.

[image]

Comment: perhaps you could fix it with tilt (ctrl T or in the N panel > Transform)? If not, could you share your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a subsurf modifier to both curve and the mesh.
2. Select the Curve in edit mode -> Tooshelf -> curve tools -> Switch Direction

If there is a gap seen in the mesh go to edit mode and scale in Z axis.

[image]